# How to avoid wrapping inline tags in PhpStorm 2016.3 when reformatting HTML?

Tags: html, formatting, phpstorm

I've got this line of code:

```
<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum velit esse cillum <strong>dolore eu fugiat.</strong></p>
```

Every time I press <kbd>Strg + Alt + L</kbd> to reformat HTML according to my settings, PhpStorm sets a newline before inline tags like `<a>` or `<strong>`, so the text above becomes

```
<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum velit esse cillum 
<strong>dolore eu fugiat.</strong>
</p>
```

I want to keep certain tags inline - like those usually used in simple paragraphs, but I can't figure out how to resolve this simple problem.

I've already added the e.g. anchor tag to "Remove newline before", "Inline elements" and "Don't break if inline content" in `Settings > Editor > Code Style > HTML`, but still no effect.

Comment: I've just tried 2016.3.2 version an your code using Default Code Style schema -- I see no new line before <strong> being inserted on reformat.

Comment: The problem still persists in `PhpStorm 2017.1.3`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you don't "Wrap text". Since a tag is no plain text, it gets wrapped.
I don't think there is a solution to this as of PhpStorm 2017.2.4.
I suggest using "Wrap text" to avoid inconsistencies.